# Turning off labels that have null values in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

How do I turn off labels that have null values?

I am using a leader with this label but I want it turned off if the values are null

Answer (score 8):

you can add a query filter to which labels will be rendered.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=About_labeling
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Displaying_labels

Check the section "Controlling which features are labelled".

Essentially, you will add a query to the label manager, something like this

```
[Attribute_being_labbeled] is not null
```

And then, nulls won't be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the layer properties label tab, select the Method drop down that says:

> define classes of features and label classes differently

you will see a box appear reading "SQL Query..."

If you then enter:

```
 "Field of your choice" <> 'Unique value of your choice'
```

So, say the field is ROAD NAME and the unique road name you do not want to be visible is NULL

You will enter:

```
"ROAD NAME" <> 'NULL'
```

Same thing as the former example, but redundancy sometimes helps. That will to it.